# SwiftUI: Image(systemName:"ellipsis") how to resize without stretching?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)        
        
    }
}
```

I creates this:

[image]

How can I make it so the image does resize to fill the entire space available but without getting deformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `scaledToFit`:

```
Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
```

[image]